# Bash -eq and ==, what's the diff?

Tags: linux, bash

Why this works:

```
Output=$( tail --lines=1 $fileDiProva )
##[INFO]Output = "OK"

if [[ $Output == $OK ]]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "No Match"
fi
```

and this not?

```
Output=$( tail --lines=1 $fileDiProva )
##[INFO]Output = "OK"

if [[ $Output -eq $OK ]]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "No Match"
fi
```

What's the difference?? between == and -eq?

Thanks!

Comment: `-eq` is for numerical comparison and `==` is for string comparison. Obviously 2nd will fail.

Comment: Comparison of integers is `-eq`. Comparison of strings is `==`.

Comment: Read the bash documentation (`info bash` if your system has it) and search for `-eq`.

Comment: BTW, `==` isn a bash extension -- being in the habit of using `=` will make it easier to write code for other shells. (Granted, `[[` is an extension too, but it's a more obvious one; I see a lot of people who get the impression that `==` is the only correct string comparison operator, and that's not true).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-eq` is an arithmetic test.

You are comparing strings.

From `help test`:

```
Other operators:

  arg1 OP arg2   Arithmetic tests.  OP is one of -eq, -ne,
                 -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.
```

When you use `[[` and use `-eq` as the operator, the shell attempts to evaluate the LHS and RHS.  The following example would explain it:

```
$ foo=something
+ foo=something
$ bar=other
+ bar=other
$ [[ $foo -eq $bar ]] && echo y
+ [[ something -eq other ]]
+ echo y
y
$ something=42
+ something=42
$ [[ $foo -eq $bar ]] && echo y
+ [[ something -eq other ]]
$ other=42
+ other=42
$ [[ $foo -eq $bar ]] && echo y
+ [[ something -eq other ]]
+ echo y
y
```

Comment: Don't see my comment, but I edited the above response to add double quotes around variable substitutions. Double quotes will force unset or empty variables to evaluate to an empty string. Otherwise, if a variable in an -eq comparison (like in the above) were empty or unset, you'd get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this explanation of if](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).

The first one `==` is in the section of string compare operators and it can only compare two strings.

The second one `-eq` is in the last section `ARG1 OP ARG2`(last one) and its documentation says `"ARG1" and "ARG2" are integers`.

Answer (score 0):

`-eq`, `-lt`, `-gt` is only used for arithmetic value comparison(integers).

`==` is used for string comparison.